# Ruby ActionMailer. Why are my images getting blocked by email clients like Yahoo?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, email, erb, actionmailer

So I am trying to send an email on my ruby on rails app using ActionMailer.  However, my images keep getting blocked on yahoo with this message "This message contains blocked images.  Show Images Change this setting".

Is it because I am using:

```
<%= image_tag("headerforemail.jpg", :alt => "header") %>
```

Should I use:

```
<img src="images/headerforemail.jpg" alt= "header") >
```

Thank you!

Comment: you can try the latter, and it might work, but it will break asset pipeline stuff.  I wonder if yahoo is blocking the remote image that the asset helper gives you do the the extra tags (Since they look like web tracking bugs).  Remote images in mail clients can be kinda iffy as lots of places block them by default

Comment: Yahoo has a setting that the user can toggle which will automatically block any images. I believe this is a Yahoo mail client issue, not anything to do with your code. I have generated HTML emails with <img> tags to remote assets with the asset pipeline which load fine in Yahoo. Try changing your settings in the Yahoo mail client and see if images will load then. https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN5043.html

Comment: Many mail clients block images by default. It has nothing to do with how you've set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Like was mentioned in the comments, quite a few email services by default will block images, unless the user has other wise set it to do other wise. So this is not an issue of your code not working. For a some what comprehensive list of email services and there image settings see the chart [here](https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-email-image-blocking)

Comment: Would it make sense to host the image on my rails app myself on like a static page?  I just don't understand how I receive responsive images on my  emails all the time?

Comment: Its pretty much out of your control with regards to images, just try to use html as effectively as you can to convey your messaging.